# Circular Definition of Experiment in probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, definition

I was trying to understand what an experiment was in the theory of probability. I found several definitions.

**Definition by Wikipedia**

> Any procedure that can be infinitely repeated and whose outcomes are well-defined.

**Standard Definition**

> An experiment is a probability space $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$

**Issue with the definitions**

So my understanding is that an experiment is used to define what a sample space is and what its outcomes are. From this we can define events and the event space. From these we can define a probability measure and therefore define the triplet $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$ to be a probability space.

Therefore a probability space is defined starting from an experiment. But an experiment is defined starting from a probability space. This is a circular definition!

**Possible solution to the issue**

My guess is that the correct definition of an experiment is

> Any procedure that can be infinitely repeated and whose outcomes are well-defined.

Or maybe the one given by Grimmett & Welsh:

> Any procedure whose consequence is not predetermined.

But surely not the one with the probability space. Rather, I would say that an experiment is *represented* by a probability space, but not defined from it!

Is this correct? Or do we allow circular definitions?

Comment: Why the downvote? It seems to be a very legitimate question

Comment: To see the interplay between mathematical definitions (which should not be circular) and vernacular definitions (such as one often finds to be circular on consulting a dictionary) you might have a look at Bernoulli trials (e.g. in Wikipedia).  It is a special case, but illustrates the distinction between a procedure that can be done one or more times and the analysis of outcomes when repetition is part of the experimental *design*.  Experiment is a word that can be used either to refer to the procedure done once or the collection of repeated performances (replication).

Comment: The main conceptual problem is with 'probability'. Sometimes, as with gambling devices such as dice and roulette wheels, the assumption that the game is honest leads directly to a (classical) specification of probability structure (1/6 th for each face, 1/38 for each slot on the wheel). Other times (frequentist) probabilities are inferred from lots of 'experimental' data, for example probability that a female high school student with A avg will total her car in next 6 mo. Also, (Bayesian / personal) prob's, such as at what odds are you willing to bet Yankees get to world series this yr.

Answer (score 2):

In a rigorous treatment of probability, the word "experiment" is not even used. You just define a sample space and probability measure without mentioning any "experiment". Now, you may be thinking in your mind that each element of the sample space corresponds to one possible outcome of a real-world "experiment" like rolling a die, but there is no need to give a precise definition to the word "experiment" (and also I don't know how to give this term a precise definition even if we wanted to).

Answer (score 0):

> So my understanding is that an experiment is used to define what a sample space is and what its outcomes are.

What you hope for them to be, it depends on the design.

See "[experimental method](https://www.colby.edu/biology/BI17x/expt_method.html)" and "[experimental design](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/experimental+design)".

> From this we can define events and the event space. From these we can define a probability measure and therefore define the triplet (Ω,Σ,P) to be a probability space. Therefore a probability space is defined starting from an experiment.

OK.

> But an experiment is defined starting from a probability space. This is a circular definition!

Chicken and the egg. Figure out one, probably the experiment and it's design, then decide what to measure.

You *could* decide what you enjoy measuring and performing statistical analysis on the most, then create an experiment.

> I was trying to understand what an experiment was in the theory of probability.

Here's one example:

In "[An Introduction to Random Sets](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/266986639_An_Introduction_to_Random_Sets)" by Hung T. Nguyen on page 13, in section "3 - Generalities on Probability", subsection "1.2 Mathematical Models for Random Phenomena", Definition 1.1:

> A mathematical model for a random experiment is a
>   probability space ($\mathcal{\Omega, A, P})$, where:
>
> $\quad\alpha$) $\Omega$ is a set, representing the sample space of the experiment,
>
> $\quad\beta$) $\mathcal{A}$ is a σ-field (representing events), i.e.:
>
> $\qquad\,\,\,\, i)\, \Omega \in \mathcal{A}$
>
> $\qquad\; ii)\, I\!\mathcal{f \, A \in A, \, then \, A^c \in A}$
>
> $\qquad iii)\, I\!\mathcal{f \, A_n \in A \, for \, n \ge  1, \, then \, \underset{n \ge 1}\bigcup A_n \in A.}$
>
> The pair ($\Omega, \mathcal{A}$) is called a measurable space.
>
> $\quad\gamma$) $\mathcal{P : A} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is a probability measure, i.e.:
>
> $\qquad\,\,\,\, a) \; \mathcal{P}(\Omega) = 1$
>
> $\qquad\,\,\,\, b) \;I\!\mathcal{f} \, \{A_n, n \ge 1\}$ is a sequence (finite or infinitely countable) of pairwise disjoint (i.e., $A_n \cap A_m = ∅ \, for \, n \ne m$) elements of $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{P}(\underset{n \ge 1}\bigcup A_n) = \underset{n \ge 1} \sum P(A_n)$, a property that is referred to as σ-additivity of $\mathcal{P}$.
>
> $\,$ For example, in sampling from a finite population $U$ with $\#(U) = N$, if we decide to select samples of given size $n$, then $\Omega = 2^U\!$, $\mathcal{A}$ = power set of 2$^U\!$, and $\mathcal{P : A} \rightarrow [0, 1]$ is defined as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{A}) = \underset{A \in \mathbb{A}} \sum P(A), \mathbb{A} \subseteq 2^U$, where for $A \in 2^U$,

> [image: Page 14 of "An Introduction to Random Sets"]

Answer (score 0):

> But surely not the one with the probability space. Rather, I would say that an experiment is *represented* by a probability space, but not defined from it!

When writing about mathematical models of real-world phenomena, it is common to speak about a part of the model with the word for the real concept it models.

For example, someone who is trying to model parliamentary negotiations, might say something like: "Let a **party** be a function that assigns to each issue space a weighted preference ordering ..." even though they know perfectly well that a political party in reality is something different than the function in his model.

The definition you have found in Wikipedia sounds like it's trying to describe a class of real-world phenomena, as part of an explanation of how to apply probability to real-world situations.

What you call a "standard definition" is part of a description of the mathematical model. (Like littleO, I am skeptical how standard that actually is, but that's not really the point, I think).

The two definitions use the same word for things at two different levels of abstraction. This is normal and usually not a cause of confusion once you're aware that they *are* two different things.